# apt-get command error not letting Ubuntu update

Tags: apt, updates, repository

every time I run `sudo apt-get update` I get an error:

> W: Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/limbo/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  The requested URL returned error: 401

This URL is not in my sources list nor do I know what I need from it, but Ubuntu's not updating without it. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I had the same issue with Bastion from Humble Bundle V over the past week. It seems there is a problem with the servers for games purchased through the software center. As answered below, disable source from the software sources menu and it will do the trick. You can enable it back later.

Comment: That source is being included from a separate file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - the filename is something like ubuntu-ppa-uploaders-limbo.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem ***fully*** (note emphasis, future readers don't want a half-working system), be sure to mark it as the accepted answer with the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 3):

The server appears to be down. Open software sources and disable the Canonical Partner repository on the first tab. Enter your password to write the config and close the window. Then, try to update again.